# Get attributes of relation laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the attributes of relation of relation, but I got problems, I don't know how do this...

CONTROLLER:

```
public function user($id) {
    $user = UserProfile::where('friendly_url', '=', $id)->with('user', 'shares.links')->first();

    foreach($user->getRelation('shares')->pluck('links') as $link) {

//HERE IS TO RETURN LINK ATTRIBUTES, EXAMPLE $link->id
        dd($link);

    }
}
```

dd($link)

```
Collection {#309 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Link {#314 ▼
      #attributes: array:14 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "title" => "Crianças índigo nascem em 2018"
      ]
```

return $link->id

```
Exception
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a collection of links on response therfore you need to iterate one more time to get the attributes.

```
 foreach($user->getRelation('shares')->pluck('links') as $link) {

           $linksAttr = $link->map(function($li) {

               retrun [

                      //here you can return link attributes
                    'linkId' => $li->id, 
                    'linkTitle'=>$li->title

                  ];
               });

           dd($linksAttr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: dd($linkAttr['linkId']); @Valter

Answer (score 0):

Since `$link` is a collection, get an object with `first()`:

```
dd($link->first()->id);
```

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it was helpful.